# Missing resources when running "puppet agent --noop"

Tags: puppet

I may have misunderstood how "**`puppet agent --noop`**" works:

In the definition of a class I set the existence of a file and I set it's user&group ownership and this is what I have when I un "**`puppet agent --noop`**" :

- If the file doesn't exist, "**`puppet agent --noop`**" works fine
- If the file exists but user or group doesn't exist, then "**`puppet agent --noop`**" fails
  complaining about the missing user or group.
- If I simply run "**`puppet agent`**" (without "**`--noop`**") it works fine: Doesn't
  matter if the user, group or file exists or not previously: it
  creates the group, the user and/or the file.

**1st question:** I suppose that the "**`--noop`**" run doesn't verify if the catalog is asking the missing resources to be created. **Isn't it?**

**2nd question:** Is there any way to do any kind of **mocking** to avoid the problem of missing resources when launching "**`--noop`**"?

Let's paste some code to show it:

```
   # yes, it should better be virtual resources
   group { $at_group:
     ensure => "present"
   } 
   user { $at_user:
     ensure     => present,
     gid        => "$at_group",
     require    => Group[$at_group],
   } 

  file { '/etc/afile':
    owner   => $at_user,
    group   => $at_group,
    mode    => '0440',
    content => template('......erb')
    require => User[$at_user]
  }
```

output:

```
# puppet agent --test --noop
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/puppet_vardir.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/facter_dot_d.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/pe_version.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/root_home.rb
Info: Caching catalog for pagent02
Info: Applying configuration version '1403055383'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Agalindotest::Install/Group[my_group]/ensure: current_value absent, should be present (noop)
Notice: /Stage[main]/Agalindotest::Install/User[my_user]/ensure: current_value absent, should be present (noop)
Error: Could not find user my_user
Error: /Stage[main]/Agalindotest::Install/File[/etc/afile]/owner: change from 1001 to my_user failed: Could not find user my_user
Error: Could not find group my_group
Error: /Stage[main]/Agalindotest::Install/File[/etc/afiles]/group: change from 1001 to my_group failed: Could not find group my_group
```

Let's show how it works if the file doesn't exist:
then "**`puppet agent --test  --noop`**" works like a charm:

```
Notice: /Stage[main]/Agalindotest::Install/Group[my_group]/ensure: current_value absent, should be present (noop)
Notice: /Stage[main]/Agalindotest::Install/User[my_user]/ensure: current_value absent, should be present (noop)
Notice: /Stage[main]/Agalindotest::Install/File[/etc/afile]/ensure: current_value absent, should be file (noop)
```

Thanks a lot!!
/ Angel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to overcome this limitation.

The `ensure` property doesn't fail just on account of a missing owner - I believe the file will just end up owned by root. That is why the output is more pleasant when the file doesn't exist.

As for the behavior with an existing file: Each resource is considered individually, and the file resource must admit failure if the group does not exist when the file is evaluated. The fact that the group would (likely) be created without `noop` cannot be easily accounted for.

As for you idea of ignoring the issue under noop conditions if there is a user resource - that has merit, I believe. Would you raise that as a feature request at Puppet's [Jira](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com)?

#### Update

As of Puppet `3.3` you can use rely on the `$clientnoop` value that is supplied by the agent along with Facter facts. Please note that tailoring your manifest to avoid failures in `noop` mode has two consequences.

1. The manifest itself becomes much less maintainable and comprehendible.
2. The reporting from `noop` runs becomes inaccurate, because the "unsafe" property values are not part of the `noop` catalog

You could build the manifest like this:

```
# this scenario does not actually call for virtual resources at all :-)
group { $at_group:
  ensure => "present"
} 
user { $at_user:
  ensure     => present,
  gid        => "$at_group",
  require    => Group[$at_group],
} 

file { '/etc/afile':
  mode    => '0440',
  content => template('......erb')
  # require => User[$at_user]  # <- not needed at all, Puppet autorequires the user and group
}

if ! $::clientnoop {
  File['/etc/afile'] {
    owner   => $at_user,
    group   => $at_group,
  }
}
```

The `owner` and `group` properties are ignored in `noop` mode, with the pros and cons as discussed above.

All things considered, I feel that this is not worth the hassle at all.